# program a led screen in JAVA (for example)

Tags: java, serial-port, led

If I have an led screen how this:

http://puu.sh/iweqM/097f48c278.jpg

Can I program an application im Java?

There are an RS232 cable. In a normal way, we have to use an application that is already done, but can I done my application for plug on the lights?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: This is so difficult to understand that I don't think you will get any answer. Have you looked at the help section about asking questions? http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

At first read the documentation of the hardware. This will (hopefully) tell you baud rate, etc. and the syntax and commands.

Afterwards write a program, that chooses the right serial port and communicates with the device.

Comment: to communicate with the device will be no problem. That where is the problem is what have I to send to say for example (plug on the firste led)? The documentation of the hardware will be always avalaible?

Comment: The rs232 protocol is absolutly vendor specific. We cannot tell you what to send for switching on the first LED, unless you provide a documentation of the vendor. Not every vendor publishes documentation.